# CSS Z-Index OVER Javascript "Survey Monkey" PNG Fade at bottom of Scroll Bar

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, colorbox

Looking to add a PNG Fade at the bottom of the our survey questionnaire box. The short questions won't show them, but for the longer ones with a vertical scroll I would like to add a slight fade at the bottom to help indicate there is more below. The scroll bar should be enough to notify people, but some people need a little more, plus its what "we" (my boss and I) want.

Here is the page I am working on: 
http://www.careersinmusic.com/template.aspx

Click the **"Click Me for Survey"** Link to Load the Survey.

QUESTION #3 is longer and uses a scroll. Click Yes for question #1 and #2 to get to the Long question #3.

Any help is always greatly appreciated, Hopefully this is enough info.

Comment: Where is your problem? It would be great to be a little bit more concrete. Don't you know how to add an transparent png to your page?

Comment: I do, I just can't get the Div to be on top of the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, give your `#PageContentDiv` a `position` style (probably `relative`).
- Then, include the PNG fade image in that div, also with a `position` (probably `absolute`)
- Give `z-index:1` to the `#PageContentDiv`, `z=index:2` to the fader image
- Set `display:none` on that fader image
- Javascript: Test if `#PageContentDiv` has been scrolled (`.scrollTop==0`)
- Javascript: Show the fader (`.style.display=''`) if scroll bar is still at 0

Key parts to remember are that elements need a `position` style to have a `z-index` applied, and that you'll need to remove the fader once the user has realized the box can be scrolled.